# How to remove this image border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, border

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxAAP.png)

This is the Image I want to add, but when I display it on the website it becomes a image with borders: [Button with border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW03H.png) (there is a background behind the button). I'm using javascript with reactjs, html and css.

Here is the code I used to display the image:

css code: [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DldxY.png)

js code: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRjJv.png)

How do I display this image without this border? I tried putting in css file border:0; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; but nothing works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add your code as an image. Simply just type it out here. Also, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking question. :)

Comment: You should add your code within your post. SO has tools to make nice posts like teh curly brackets in the menu. Other than that it is unclear what you refer to .. Perhaps the image offset. Put `display:block;` in your CSS

Comment: Put the image URL inside the `src` attribute

Answer (score 3):

Try `border-style: none;`.
Your question isn't very concise, but it should work.. I think.. You should probably add in some more details

But really, I would never use an image in place of a button. Do this instead:

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="">Contato</button>
```

Comment: It stills the same :/ When I remove width and height properties, the image don't display anymore. I tried to change it's layer using z-index but it didn't have any effect and the image continued invisible. Also, if and alt prop isn't null, the image loose the border but look what happens:

js code: http://imgur.com/qch90a5l.png
result: http://imgur.com/osYGGSGl.png

Comment: The z-index shouldn't have any effect on it. Can you perhaps edit your post so that the relevant lines of html is included, as well as the css?

Comment: @Hockpond why would you want to use the image? Just remove the image entirely and use the above `button` element with css, or use an `a href` like in your example images, but just use plain css to achieve this look instead of adding an image inside.

Comment: Hey @Hockpond, any word on whether you are going for the image button or the html and css button?